# Why my async fetch doesn't work client side?

Tags: fetch, nuxt.js

I'm having an issue to get my `component` working client side with `fetch` (it's ok when I'm refreshing the page) in Nuxt.

The `$fetchState.error` doesn't load any error though. But my `console.log` in my `mounted` hook doesn't load any data.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here. I'm using `target: 'static'`

```
<template>
  <p v-if="$fetchState.pending">Fetching realisation...</p>
  <p v-else-if="$fetchState.error">An error occurred :(</p>
  <nuxt-link v-else :to="real.full_slug" class="real">
    <div class="real__content">
      <h2>{{ real.name }}</h2>
    </div>
  </nuxt-link>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    realisation: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      real: {}
    }
  },
  async fetch() {
    this.real = await this.$storyapi
      .get(`cdn/stories/${this.realisation.work}`, {
        version: 'published',
        find_by: 'uuid'
      })
      .then((res) => {
        return res.data.story
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err))
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.real)
  },
  fetchOnServer: true
}
</script>
```

Comment: move to a page that doesn't use the component, then navigate to a page that does.. does that make it work?

Comment: also you should change the `.then/.catch` to `try/catch`, your already await'ing it

Comment: @LawrenceCherone, no that's my issue, it doesn't work when navigating through nuxt links. Thanks for the `try/catch` :)
I'm using `target: 'static'`in my config by the way.

Comment: my thinking was, components are loaded, cached and mounted once, it might fetch clientside or serverside but if the component is loaded it won't fetch again unless you destroy it or add a watcher, like `watch:{'$route.path'(){this.$fetch()}}`, despite what it says  *..and on client-side when navigating*

Comment: btw, if its `target: 'static'` its not firing serverside, that would only work if you SSR

Comment: [in the docs](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/data-fetching), it says *For static hosting , the fetch hook is only called during page generation, and the result is then cached for use on the client. To avoid cache conflicts, it may be necessary to specify a name for your component, or alternatively provide a unique fetchKey implementation.*

Comment: The watcher doesn't work for me. It's not working either if I'm using `targer: 'server'`. So I think, the last option would be to destroy the fetch, maybe with a `beforeDestroy`hook?

Comment: Ah interesting! Thanks @LawrenceCherone, I'm gonna try that!

Comment: if you want it not cached on generate, i.e its not fetched and all the data plopped  into json, id move all the code out the fetch() into a method called getItem(), then call it in the created hook and again in a watcher like shown above, then you have best of both, but it depends on the $storyapi instance and if it uses auth that's hidden away, if it's wide open then sure just recall the API on created/mounted and when route changes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237850/discussion-between-davidgourdet-and-lawrence-cherone).